# Custom attributes for files/folders in Windows 7 possible?

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, file-management

Is there any way to tag folders/files in Windows 7 with custom attributes, that would be applicable to any file format (not stored within a file)?

For example, to create artificial folders (allowing items to belong to multiple folders), to make custom quantitative properties (like rating), etc, that would show up as a new column in details view in Windows Explorer.

Answer (score 0):

If you know C++, then this is easily possible.

You'll need to write custom Shell extensions that alter the way Explorer sees files and folders.  You can make items belong to more than one folder (heck you can define whatever you want as a folder).  You can also write custom Property Sheets, which are the tabs that show up when you rightclick and click Properties.

Comment: Easy is relative, but you're either a Winapi rock star or you're insane.

Comment: @afrazier: Yes, the premise is "If you know C++", which, in my books, puts you in the top tier of all software junkies.